# Escape JavaScript in Expression Language

Tags: javascript, jsf, escaping, el

Sometimes, I need to render a JavaScript variable using EL in a JSF page.

E.g.

```
<script>var foo = '#{bean.foo}';</script>
```

or

```
<h:xxx ... onclick="foo('#{bean.foo}')" />
```

This fails with a JS syntax error when the EL expression evaluates to a string containing JS special characters such as apostrophe and newline. How do I escape it?

Comment: The answer below put me on the correct track.

Comment: added: xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" and in the code '#{fn:replace(_selectedItem.item.webName,"'","")}',

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons Lang 3.x](http://commons.apache.org/lang) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeEcmaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)) method for this in EL.

First create a `/WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml` which look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://example.com/functions</namespace>

    <function>
        <name>escapeJS</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then register it in `/WEB-INF/web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```xml
<html ... xmlns:func="http://example.com/functions">
...
<script>var foo = '#{func:escapeJS(bean.foo)}';</script>
...
<h:xxx ... onclick="foo('#{func:escapeJS(bean.foo)}')" />
```

Alternatively, if you happen to already use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can also just use its builtin [`of:escapeJS()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings) function:

```
<html ... xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
...
<script>var foo = '#{of:escapeJS(bean.foo)}';</script>
...
<h:xxx ... onclick="foo('#{of:escapeJS(bean.foo)}')" />
```

Comment: I've followed the above, but I'm getting the following exception : javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.faces.el.impl.ElException: No function is mapped to the name "util:escapeJS"   I'm on JSF 1.1, JSP 2.1... any idea what I should look at?

Comment: @bendicott: Above answer uses a Facelet taglib. You're using JSP, not Facelets. You need to create a JSP taglib instead.

Comment: Had to correct the taglib-definition but your solution is great... simple and effective!

Comment: We're using JSF 1 with Facelets (legacy), so we needed to use the version 1 taglib DTD rather than the version 2 schema, and the `web.xml` property is facelets.LIBRARIES rather than javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES, but the basic idea of this answer was applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `\'#{_selectedItem.item.webName}\',`?

Comment: Read the question once again. It's `webName` which returns an apostrophed string value.