# How should I handle HTML Entities in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, html-encode

I'm working to upgrade an old web program written in PHP with a MySQL database as the backend.

The database is full of text like this `&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;`

Which obviously is an encoded form of `<P><STRONG><FONT size=4>`

How can I get a JSF file to render that properly ? Outputting it as escaped text gives me the 1st line, and unescaped text gives me the 2nd line.

I want the HTML to appear **as html** in the document, I'll accept the risk of doing so :)

Am I better off decoding the text in the database ?  I'm not sure that this is a format I want to work with in the future, but I have so little experience with HTML entities that I'm just not sure the best long-term route.

Anything from technical knowhow to the ramblings of wise old sages is welcome here.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by _"I want the HTML to appear as html in the document?"_ Do you want to literally display the text `<P><STRONG><FONT size=4>` or do you want to **render** a paragraph with bold text, size 4?

Comment: By the way, the HTML `<font>` tag is deprecated since 1998.

Comment: Originally I'd wanted to display the document with rendered markup, when the DB contains the HTML for a table, I'd want to render a table. Now that I'm rereading my original question, I'm wondering if that's the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How can I get a JSF file to render that properly ? Outputting it as escaped text gives me the 1st line, and unescaped text gives me the 2nd line.*

Wrap [`StringEscapeUtils#unescapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) in an EL function ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617155/is-there-a-way-to-escape-apostrophes-in-jsp-expression-language/6617219#6617219)) and display it in an `<h:outputText>` with `escape="false"`.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{util:unescapeHtml(bean.value)}" escape="false" />
```

The function will turn `&lt;` to `<` and so on, the `escape="false"` will prevent JSF from re-escaping it in order to prevent user-controlled input from being literally interpreted which can possibly create XSS holes.

---

> *Am I better off decoding the text in the database? I'm not sure that this is a format I want to work with in the future, but I have so little experience with HTML entities that I'm just not sure the best long-term route.*

Not storing HTML in the DB at all is the best option. If there is really no other option, then I'd opt for decoding them straight in the DB.

Comment: What is this notation `util:unescapeHtml`?  Is that a Java 8 method reference with one colon?

Comment: @jordanpg: Click the "example here" link.

Comment: So it's a custom Facelets (JSP?) tag inside a value expression?  Is that really the intended use case of custom tags?  IOW, what is the advantage of doing that over just using a managed bean, eg. `utilBean.unescape(x)`?

Comment: It's not a custom tag. It's an EL function. It isn't possible to invoke static methods on a (stateful!) managed bean.

Comment: Looks like a custom tag to me:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-custom008.htm#BNAWN

I also note in passing that I never saw "EL function" in the official docs:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm#GJDDD

Comment: Also, I still don't see what the advantage of defining `util:method(x)` over `utilBean.method(x)` is.  Doesn't need to be static.