# Print managed bean property as JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm trying to print java string return values into script java .
this is my method in java class

```
public static String getchamps (){ //Bdconnection class
    String str;
    {
        str = "date" ;
    }

    return str ;
}
```

the question is how can i have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    "date"
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have any problems with your solution?

Comment: Question is incomplete

Comment: i added the question

Comment: Please find answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should in this context look at JSF as a HTML code generator. You can use JSF tags/components and EL expressions to let it produce the desired HTML output. As JavaScript is as being a client side language technically part of HTML (not of JSF!), you can just do the same for JavaScript.

Once you fix that bad static method to really comply the Javabeans specification as below:

```
public String getChamps() {
    return "date";
}
```

Then you can just let JSF print it as if it's a JS variable as below:

```
<script>
    var champs = "#{bean.champs}";
</script>
```

To verify the result, just open the JSF page in webbrowser and do rightclick, *View Source*. You should see something similar to:

```
<script>
    var champs = "date";
</script>
```

Beware of JS-special characters in the string though! This would fail if the string contains e.g. a doublequote or even a newline. If that's the case, then you'd better escape it using an EL function as shown in this answer: [Escape JavaScript in Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617155/escape-javascript-in-expression-language).

Comment: #{bean.champs}
my class is
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

 
@ManagedBean
public class Bdconnection {
 public String str = "date";
 public String getchamps(){
  
   return str ;
   }
     
}
i tried #{Bdconnection.str} but does'nt work

Comment: Just exactly follow the example in the answer. Your method name is still wrong and the way how you referenced the property in EL is still wrong. The answer shows the proper way. I'm not sure why you keep trying doing things the different way.

Comment: If you're unable to elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's terms, I suggest to take a pause, put this all aside, and carefully go through a sane JSF book to properly grasp the basic concepts. Then, once you're finished and come back to this all, you'll surely quickly spot your mistake.

Comment: it works finally thank you , in fact i had a problem in my bean ! thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
<h:inputText id="propertyId" value="#{Bdconnection.str}" />
```

and access in script

```
document.getElementById('propertyId').val();
```

Comment: i want to get Bdconnection.str from my class not from an input text

Comment: If you want to access your String you have to store it in the Session or you could use a Bean.

Comment: to complex as solution for the original problem and  not easily refactorable (via IDE) etc...